# How to have one to one relationship but keep track of all records at the same time - Django relationships

Tags: django, model

I have this below models where PostingOrder gets created when Posting is created. When Posting gets reposted a new `PostingOrder` gets created. I want to have one current PostingOrder per Posting but also want to be able to track all PostingOrders per Posting.

My current issue is that when I query `PostingOrder` with a specific Posting I'm getting multiple PostingOrder queryset. I could get the current PostingOrder by filtering for the recently created but I feel like this is not a good approach.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
class Posting(models.Model):
    title = ...
    author = ....

class PostingOrder(models.Model):
    posting = models.ForeignKey(Posting)
    order_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    payment_method = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=PAYMENT_METHOD_CHOICES)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: So one posting can have multiple posting order?

Comment: FIltering for the recently created object is honestly not bad practice, that way you avoid adding any additional tables and have easy access to all your PostingOrder objects.

Comment: @subha.py correct, when a user wants to edit and post that same posting again they have to pay therefore a new order gets created but the posting is the same.